# How to Join (NOT COMBINE) two more django querysets?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I’m new to Django framework, may be this problem seem to be fun to some experienced developers here.

So, I have a django model:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (‘CL’, ‘CLOSED’),
    (‘FR’, ‘FORWARDED’),
    (‘PE’),
)

class References(modles.Model):
    ref_no = models.CharField(max_length=)
    date_received = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

I am required to query the data in this format:-

| Year | Month | #Total Ref. | #CLOSED | #FORWARDED | #PENDING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | Jan | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023 | Feb | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023 | Mar | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Sample data:

| Ref_No (unique) | Date_Recieved | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC-123 | 01-Jan-2023 | CLOSED |
| BCD-234 | 01-Feb-2023 | FORWARDED |
| DEF-567 | 01-Jan-2023 | PENDING |
| ABC-891 | 01-Jan-2023 | CLOSED |
| DEF-967 | 01-Mar-2023 | PENDING |

I created three different querysets but don’t know how to join them to produce above results: -

```
# TOTAL
q_total = References.objects.all() \
.values('date_received__year', 'date_received__month') \
.annotate(dcount=Count(‘ref_no’)) \
.order_by('date_received__year', ‘date_received__month')

# CLOSED
q_total = References.objects.filter(Q(status__iexact='CL') \
.values('date_received__year', 'date_received__month') \
.annotate(dcount=Count(‘ref_no’)) \
.order_by('date_received__year', ‘date_received__month')

# FORWARDED
q_total = References.objects.filter(Q(status__iexact='FR') \
.values('date_received__year', 'date_received__month') \
.annotate(dcount=Count(‘ref_no’)) \
.order_by('date_received__year', ‘date_received__month')

# PENDING
q_total = References.objects.filter(Q(status__iexact='PE') \
.values('date_received__year', 'date_received__month') \
.annotate(dcount=Count(‘ref_no’)) \
.order_by('date_received__year', ‘date_received__month')
```

Any help would be appreciated. The above is just a small sample problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to JOIN or merge, you can do this all in the same queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

q_total = (
    References.objects.values('date_received__year', 'date_received__month')
    .annotate(
        closed_count=Count('ref_no', filter=Q(status__iexact='CL')),
        forward_count=Count('ref_no', filter=Q(status__iexact='FR')),
        pending_count=Count('ref_no', filter=Q(status__iexact='PE')),
    )
    .order_by('date_received__year', 'date_received__month')
)
```

for each row it will thus have three attributes: `.closed_count`, `.forward_count`, `.pending_count`.

Comment: When annotating on more than one field, it is important to remember there is a chance of getting incorrect results. With `Count` function, you can pass the `distinct=True` to avoid this easy oversight.

Comment: @McPherson: that is when you would JOIN on *multiple* models, in which case the two act as a multipler of each other. `distinct=True` might help, but not always, for example if the thing you count/sum/... are not per se unique. For example `Sum('amount', distinct=True)` for bank transfers would only sum up the amounts that are different, so if you would withdraw two times 50 USD, that would only count as one.

Comment: Here we don't JOIN on multiple models, in fact we do not JOIN at all, it just counts the same table, hence there is no change of this "multiplier" effect. The incorrect results will happen if there are two `JOIN`s, such that the same rows are passed to the aggregates multiple times.

Comment: Ah, yeah. That was my oversight.